# .eh_frame FDE - where can the field "initial location" / address range be found/resolved?

Tags: c++, c, linux, elf, dwarf

When reading about sections like `.eh_frame` and `.debug_frame` in the DWARF standard it says that in `Frame Description Entries` (FDE) there is a field that's called:

```
address_range (target address)
The number of bytes of program instructions described by this entry.
```

The linux foundation (https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/ehframechpt.html) also documents this field as

```
PC Begin    Required
PC Range    Required
```

But when reading the raw bytes there's no addresses there to be found. Normally, in other DWARF-related debug data, the addresses are actually stored, as bytes representing the actual addresses, or some offset from some location, so that an address range can be resolved by parsing that location first.

Here, there seems to be no such thing and I can't find *any* documentation *at all* on how to parse this "initial location" (or PC Begin | PC Range). The data is not large enough to represent 8 bytes, so it's not just a matter of "reading the bytes" as it were.

Does anyone have any pointers on where one can read about this?

Comment: "The data is not large enough to represent 8 bytes" -- DWARF data is compressed using e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LEB128

Comment: That's not it, but thanks anyway. Apparently, after _much_ trial and error since the documentation is incredibly sparse - the data is actually relative to the virtual memory address the section is mapped in to, at run time; so those 4 bytes is a negative (most often) offset, which points into the .text section.

Besides, DWARF does not use LEB128 for addresses. In an overwhelming majority LEB128 is used for other things, like offsets from a base address.